# Managed switch stopping my system working

Tags: switch

I am attempting to get an embedded board working that using TCP/IP and UDP/IP. I have it working so that I can issue HTTP POST and GET commands and UDP works fine but am struggling with SNTP, so I have bought a managed switch so I can mirror what my embedded board is sending out and try to track NTP packets in and out.

I have the following set-up:

Embedded board 192.168.0.200
Desktop running Apache server on Linux: 192.168.0.65 (Also sends receives custom UDP packets).

Using a normal switch the embedded board can GET and POST with the Apache server just fine and Wireshark, running on 192.168.0.65 can capture the packets.

However, if I connect up the Linux machine and the embedded board to the managed switch, the GET and POST stops working. The ACK of the SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK doesn't work properly and the whole system fails to POST and GET correctly.

I have the embedded board connected to port 2 and the desktop to port 5. I have selected, on the switch management web page that the *mirroring* port is port 5 and *mirrored* port 2, with port 2 ingress and egress enabled. I've tried that the other way round too, so that mirroring port is port 2 and mirrored is port 5.

This is the first time I've ever used a managed switch so I'm probably doing something incredibly naive or stupid. Is this enough information to help advise me what I might be doing wrong? If not, I will supply any info that would help.

Many thanks!

[image: Here's a JPEG of the set-up using the web interface for the switch]

Comment: "managed switch" is a very broad term. Please tell us the brand, type and show relevant configuration.

Comment: It's TP-Link TL-SG3424. Are you looking for a screenshot of how I've set it up using the web interface?

Comment: If so, I've added that now.

Comment: I'm confused.  The desktop is running the Apache server?  So there's only two devices- the board and the desktop?

Comment: Yes, Ron. Only two devices. Desktop which is my main machine is also running an Apache server. This is the machine running Wireshark too. Is that the issue? Do I need a third machine to do all the sniffing and leave the desktop and embedded board to work as normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED>

Yes you need a third machine.  The port that receives the mirrored traffic can't receive regular traffic.  That's why things aren't working.  If you have a second interface on your desktop, you could possibly use that and bind Wireshark to that interface.

Comment: No, it can't, because when the embedded board sends out NTP requests it goes nowhere near the desktop. This is when I need the managed switch so I can sniff packets that are not bound for the desktop.

Comment: I see.  The ntp destination is a different address?  What device is that?

Comment: The NTP device is a server out on the Internet. For the now I have just chosen an IP address that my desktop queries when it is getting its NTP timestamps.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect this new information.

Comment: Smashing, thanks. I'll dig out my laptop and get Wireshark going on that then.